# Getting the last and oldest price of a grouped row

Tags: mysql

I have this query and I want to select the currentprice(the most current price sorted by time) and the oldprice(the last row sorted by time) in the same columns per row. I figured out how to select the currentprice but how can I select both in the same query?

In the end I want to make a calculation for the percentage of gain or drop with `ROUND((latestprice - oldprice) / oldprice * 100, 2) as gain_ratio`

```
WITH tmp AS ( 
  SELECT TrackID, ID, price, MAX(Time) as maxtime, MIN(Time) as mintime
  FROM track
  WHERE Time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR 
  GROUP BY ID
)
SELECT T.TrackID, T.ID, tmp.Price as currentprice, T.Time
FROM track AS T
JOIN tmp ON T.ID = tmp.ID
WHERE T.Time = tmp.maxtime;
```

I'm really struggeling to grasp how to make a CTE query, I have read the documentation several times

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your where clause to...?:

```
WHERE T.Time = tmp.maxtime or T.Time = tmp.mintime
```

Comment: Oh i think i made a mistake in my question, i meant i want the oldest price (so first row sorted by time) and the newest price(so last row)